# SimpleXMLElement xpath query with same childnode names

Tags: php, json, soap, simplexml

I've have a SOAP response XML like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:VizsgaHelyszinLekerdezValasz xmlns:ns2="...">
      <MegyeKir>
        <MegyeKir>id_1</MegyeKir>
        <KirendeltsegNev>KirendeltsegNev_1</KirendeltsegNev>
        <VizsgaHelyszin>
          <Nev>Nev_1</Nev>
          <VizsgaHelyszinKod>9020</VizsgaHelyszinKod>
          <ElmeletiVizsgaTipus>Bü</ElmeletiVizsgaTipus>
          <GyakorlatiVizsgaTipus>F</GyakorlatiVizsgaTipus>
        </VizsgaHelyszin>
        <VizsgaHelyszin>
          <Nev>Nev2</Nev>
          <VizsgaHelyszinKod>823020</VizsgaHelyszinKod>
          <GyakorlatiVizsgaTipus>Jk</GyakorlatiVizsgaTipus>
        </VizsgaHelyszin>
      </MegyeKir>
      <MegyeKir>
        <MegyeKir>id_2</MegyeKir>
        <KirendeltsegNev>KirendeltsegNev_2</KirendeltsegNev>
        <VizsgaHelyszin>
          <Nev>Nev_1</Nev>
          <VizsgaHelyszinKod>9020</VizsgaHelyszinKod>
          <GyakorlatiVizsgaTipus>Bü</GyakorlatiVizsgaTipus>
          <GyakorlatiVizsgaTipus>F</GyakorlatiVizsgaTipus>
        </VizsgaHelyszin>
        <VizsgaHelyszin>
          <Nev>Nev2</Nev>
          <VizsgaHelyszinKod>823020</VizsgaHelyszinKod>
          <GyakorlatiVizsgaTipus>Jk</GyakorlatiVizsgaTipus>
        </VizsgaHelyszin>
    </MegyeKir>
   </ns2:VizsgaHelyszinLekerdezValasz>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'd like to create a JSON object from it in the following way:

```
$response_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

$response_xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$megyekir = $response_xml->xpath("//soap:Body//MegyeKir");

echo json_encode($megyekir);
```

The problem: because the "MegyeKir" node has a same "MegyeKir" child node in the JSON output the child not located under the "MegyeKir" but in a separate key:

```
0: {MegyeKir: "id_1", KirendeltsegNev: "KirendeltsegNev_1", VizsgaHelyszin: [,…]}
1: {0: "id_1"}
2: {MegyeKir: "id_2", KirendeltsegNev: "KirendeltsegNev_2",…}
3: {0: "id_2"}
```

How can I skip these elements from the JSON array?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `//soap:Body//MegyeKir` with the second `//` indicates to XPath to find all elements at all levels.  If you only want the main element, you should limit this.

As there is only 1 layer between the `<Body>` tag and the `<MegyeKir>` you are after, you chould use `/*/` which allows only 1 level between the two tags...

```
$megyekir = $response_xml->xpath("//soap:Body/*/MegyeKir");
```

Comment: Can you help me how can I query only those "MegyeKir"s which has a "ElmeletiVizsgaTipus" child node?

Comment: If it's a direct descendant then `//soap:Body/*/MegyeKir[ElmeletiVizsgaTipus]`

Comment: I've tried this solution but somehow it gives me empty result :-(

Comment: Just checked and it's not a direct descendant, so try `//soap:Body/*/MegyeKir[*/ElmeletiVizsgaTipus]`

Comment: This one returns all "MegyeKir" nodes not just with "ElmeletiVizsgaTipus"

Comment: Not as far as I can tell.